# Improving the time complexity of all permutations of a given string

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

The problem is generally posed as given a string, print all permutations of it. For eg, the permutations of string ABC are ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA.

The standard solution is a recursive one, given below.

```
void permute(char *a, int i, int n) 
{
   int j; 
   if (i == n)
     printf("%s\n", a);
   else
   {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
       {
          swap((a+i), (a+j));
          permute(a, i+1, n);
          swap((a+i), (a+j)); //backtrack
       }
   }
}
```

This, runs into `O(n*n!)`. Is this the best we can do or is there someway to make this faster?

Comment: I think only with multithreading

Comment: Even with multithreading, it's an insignificant factor of speedup compared to `O(n!)` - it's equivalent to `O(n!/k)` for `k` threads, which is still `O(n!)`

Comment: Is it really necessary to actually manipulate the string? Can't you just print it's permutation right away, by printing each char in the correct order, this way you save a lot of swaps..

Comment: @Vladp To my knowledge, this is one of the most efficient (recursive) ways of generating permutations. Swapping really isn't that expensive. If you have a concrete algorithm that just prints the permutations 'right away', feel free to post it.

Comment: @Dukeling look at "son of the northern darkness" solution, and my comment to it.

Comment: @Vladp With respect to your comment, I don't really see why constructing and changing an integer array is that much better than changing a char array (actually I think it's worse).

Comment: @Dukeling since this is a function from the std library I highly doubt that writing your own version would improve something, I'm even sure it will be slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::next_permutation`. Please, notice it works correctly only on sorted array.
Good points about this solution:
1) It is standard
2) It is non-recursive

Here is an example (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/):

```
// next_permutation example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::next_permutation, std::sort

int main () {
  int myints[] = {1, 2, 3};

  std::sort (myints, myints + 3);

  std::cout << "The 3! possible permutations with 3 elements:\n";
  do {
    std::cout << myints[0] << ' ' << myints[1] << ' ' << myints[2] << '\n';
  } while (std::next_permutation (myints, myints + 3));

  std::cout << "After loop: " << myints[0] << ' ' << myints[1] << ' ' << myints[2] << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good solution, now if you need string permutation just print string.at(myints[i]). It's really unnecessary to change the string it self.

Answer (score 0):

The very result you are looking for contains n*n elements, so this is the best you can get!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `n` elements and you are looking for `k`th permutation  `0 <= k <= n-1`.

- Create a list `elements` with all elements and an empty list `result`
- `while elements not empty`:

  - Set `p = k % elements.size` and `k = k / elements.size`
  - Remove `elements[p]` and append it to `result`

We visit each element from `elements` only once so it's O(n).

Answer (score 0):

`std::next_permutation` does the job:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    char s[] = "BAC";

    // let's begin with the lowest lexicographically string.
    std::sort(std::begin(s), std::end(s) - 1); // '- 1' : ignore '\0'
    do {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    } while (std::next_permutation(std::begin(s), std::end(s) - 1));
  return 0;
}
```