# Matrix and submatrix of permutations

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, permutation

I need a matrix of all permutations of N elements. Indeed, its dimension will be N x N! A special property of this matrix is that each submatrix with dimension K x K! (K < N) must be a matrix of all permutations of K elements. There are obviously many valid solutions but I am interested in the simplest (but efficient) plain C-style algorithm to generate just one matrix of this kind (without STL and other advanced libraries).

To clarify the question, here is the form of the generated matrix. The second column starts with one "2", the third column starts with two "3", the i-th column starts with (i-1)! elements "i". There are no other requirements on the  ordering of permutations, just make the algorithm simple.

```
1 2 3 4 5 ...
2 1 3 4 5 ...
* * * 4 5 ...
* * * 4 5 ...
* * * 4 5 ...
* * * 4 5 ...
* * * * 5 ...
...
```

Comment: "There are obviously many valid solutions" - you should add one or two to your question, because currently the question doesn't show any attempt at solving the problem yourself, which it should for [so] questions.

Comment: Many solutions = many matrices with the given property. This is not homework, it may be simple but I cannot find any solution beyond using nested loops and checking if element in the row differ from all others on its left side. It would be nice if there exist a solution with producing new line by swaping two elements of the previous line.

Comment: Look up the Johnson-Trotter Algorithm, here's a link http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Combinatorics/JohnsonTrotter.shtml

Comment: Probably you could use the code from this http://stackoverflow.com/q/20991167/2549281 question, modifying it so it will record permutations into a matrix

Comment: @nonsensickle Johnson-Trotter Algorithm does not give the correct matrix. For n=4 I get (1234),(1243),(1423),(4123),...,(4213),(2413),(2143),(2134) which does not have required property in any direction (bottom-up,up-bottom,left-right,right-left).

Comment: @David Well, this is a good suggestion. I was able to adapt algorithm from that question to get the desired result. I will give it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood the problem ;-) - The solution is based on the observation that a KxK! submatrix anchored at a[1,1] can be extended by a) adding K+1 to the K! rows, b) copying the row vectors of the first K! rows repeatedly, i.e., K times, into rows K+1..(K+1)!, while replacing for each group of K! rows the value 1..K by K+1 and storing K into column K+1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 6
#define NF (1*2*3*4*5*6)

int p[NF][N];

int main( int argc, char* args[] ){
  int n, i, k, iCol, iRow;
  int row = 0;

  for( n = 0; n < N; n++ ){
    if( n == 0 ){
      p[row][n] = n+1;
      row++;
    } else {
      // add new value n+1 to all existing rows
      for( i = 0; i < row; i++ ){
        p[i][n] = n+1;
      }
      // for all numbers 1..n
      int nextRow = row;
      for( k = 1; k <= n; k++ ){
        // pass through all rows so far
        for( iRow = 0; iRow < row; iRow++ ){
          // copy row
          for( iCol = 0; iCol < n; iCol++ ){ 
            int h = p[iRow][iCol];
            p[nextRow][iCol] = h == k ? n+1 : h;
          }
          p[nextRow][n] = k;
          nextRow++;
        }
      }
      row = nextRow;
    }
  }
  for( iRow = 0; iRow < NF; iRow++ ){
    for( iCol = 0; iCol < N; iCol++ ){
      printf( "%3d", p[iRow][iCol] );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
  }
}
```

Comment: This works. However, I cannot decide if this has any advantage over the recursive solution posted by myself. Comment on this, please!

Comment: Timing with N=11 suggests that my solution is faster. I compared the times required to fill an int[N!][N] array.

Comment: [Live demo's](https://ideone.com/6ldwI9) (or at least some example input and output) always helps. Also, don't forget a `return` statement for your `main` function.

Comment: @Dukeling Gosh, 15 years since I wrote my last C program, and look at my blunders ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working program using the algorithm from the question [Improving the time complexity of all permutations of a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991167/improving-the-time-complexity-of-all-permutations-of-a-given-string)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 6
#define NF (1*2*3*4*5*6)

int p[NF][N];

void swap (int *a, int i, int j)
{
   int tmp;
   tmp = a[i];
   a[i] = a[j];
   a[j] = tmp;
}
void permute(int *a, int i, int n)
{
   int j;
   static int k=0;
   if (i == n) {
     for (j=0; j<N; j++) p[k][j] = a[N-j-1];
     k++;
   }
   else for (j=i; j<=n; j++) {
      swap(a,i,j);
      permute(a,i+1,n);
      swap(a,i,j);
   }
}
int main() {
  int i,j,a[N];
  for (i=0; i<N; i++) a[i] = N-i;
  permute(&a,0,N-1);
  for(i=0;i<NF;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<N;j++) {
      printf("%3d",p[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: @laune I have changed this solution to follow your style. Yes, your solution is faster.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is so. My notebook is into paging due to int p[][], and accurate timing isn't possible any more. Using a char p[][] produces entirely different results. -- But why is efficiency so important (except as an academic issue)? If you need the data, create it once and keep it on a file. If you need different data being permuted, use the stored permutations of 1..N to map a permutation of whatever is being permuted now. -- It *may* be possible to speed up my algo in the replicating loop, but it's tricky, and I don't see any cogent reason to invest more time. Sorry.

Comment: @laune Thanks for your work! As you correctly guessed, I need data, they will be produced only once and thus timing is a minor issue. And yes, it was my academic pedigree which prevent me from immediatelly accepting your answer although it is very correct and directly usable.